# In Linux,pdftoppm command is running two processes for single file

Tags: linux, pdf, ppm

```
root@test:/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/logs# ps aux | grep ppm
root     25522  0.0  0.0   1844   500 ?        SN   14:13   0:00 sh -c /bin/bash -c "pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 /pdf/input.pdf test/processing/output"
 root     25523 49.6  0.7  18192 12620 ?        RN   14:13   0:59 pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 /pdf/input.pdf /test/processing/output
root     25539  0.0  0.0   2016   636 ?        R+   14:15   0:00 grep ppm
```

I am not familiar with this command. Why two processes are running I can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *not* two `pdftoppm` processes.  The following is the `pdftoppm` process:

```
root     25523 49.6  0.7  18192 12620 ?        RN   14:13   0:59 pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 /pdf/input.pdf /test/processing/output
```

The following is the process for the *shell* command:

```
root     25522  0.0  0.0   1844   500 ?        SN   14:13   0:00 sh -c /bin/bash -c "pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 /pdf/input.pdf test/processing/output"
```

The first line in your `grep` output is for the shell command that was executed.  The second line was for the actual `pdftoppm` invocation.  The third line was for the `grep`.  (Both your shell command and `grep` contained the string `pdftoppm`, which were a part of the process list when queried.)

Comment: Can you explain little bit more

Comment: @Mann Put the command you executed in a script instead and execute the script.  You'll figure.

Comment: ..I am a newbie in linux, I got to know that,pdftoppm is subprocess,But I am not able to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script is most likely excuted via a `system` call (that's what it would be in c). This system call invokes a command processor (PID 25522 in your case) to interpret the command.

The command itselves is the process with PID 25523.

In C the `exec` command family executes a command *without* invoking a command line interpreter.